# French website Providing Instruction/Tutorials on Statistical Theory

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, references

This is somewhat of an odd question for CV, but since it's a question about statistical education, I think it falls within the scope of CV.  Several years ago I stumbled across a French website that provided graduate-level statistical education in English.  I am trying to locate that website now, but I cannot, for the life of me, seem to locate the site.  I'm hoping through a description here someone who might be familiar with the website can provide me with a link.

Here is what I recall of the website:

It was not from a University or other traditional school, but appeared to be authored by a small organization (or perhaps a single individual).  It may have even been geared to students in actuarial sciences.  I do recall that many parts of the website were free, but some parts could be unlocked by paying a one-time nominal fee via credit card (I think it was less than $5 US).  The website also had a downloadable companion site as well so you could view the tutorials offline.  What I recall most is that many of the tutorials had really great animated graphics.  For example, I distinctly remember a really nice graphical representation of the Probability Integral Transform similar to [this one](https://youtu.be/TzKANDzAXnQ?t=289) on YouTube only the one on the website wasn't a video, but like an animated gif.

If anyone might have any idea what website I'm talking about, could you provide possible suggestions in comments or answers?

Thank you so much.  I'm trying to find this for a project that we hope to model this after, and I'd like to also share that with a few grad students.

Comment: This is repeatedly closed and reopened. I cannot see why this is off-topic.

Comment: Agreed, @kjetilbhalvorsen.  It would at least be helpful to understand by commenting why folks feel this is off-topic to that it could be resolved.